# Receive data from specific address using QUdpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtnetwork, qudpsocket

I'm trying to do a client-to-client communication over UDP. I'm using `QUdpSocket` to do that.

The IP of my first client is 127.0.0.2 and the IP of the second client is 127.0.0.3.

In my first client, I want to send data, so I'm doing this:

```cpp
socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
socket->bind(QHostAddress("127.0.0.2"), (quint16)actual_port);

...

Data = QByteArray::fromRawData((const char *)stockR.data, crypt_packet.size_struct); 
socket->writeDatagram(Data, QHostAddress("127.0.0.3"), (quint16)port_other);
```

In my second client, I have this:

```cpp
socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
socket->bind(QHostAddress("127.0.0.3"), (quint16)port_second);
     
...

QByteArray buffer;
buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
QHostAddress sender;
quint16 senderPort;
socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, &senderPort);
```

But I can't receive my data from `readDatagram()`, and I don't know why.

I do every function on both sides, which means I read and write on both clients (it's to do a VoIP call).

Does anyone know what my mistake is?

Comment: How is that last block called? Is it in response to a `readyRead` signal? Is `socket->hasPendingDatagrams()` true?

Comment: I don't use socket->hasPendingDatagrams and readyRead neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readDatagram` method is non-blocking: you can only usefully call it if `hasPendingDatagrams()` is true. This flag is in turn governed by running the Qt event loop.

You have two options:

- Use `socket->waitForReadyRead()` to block your program for a set time (30s);
- Or put the above code in a slot handler connected to the `readyRead` signal and let the event loop run naturally, keeping your application responsive to other inputs.